# Screens of different sizes in Android Studio

Tags: android

When I put an image in a certain place by the `setx` /`sety`  function on a different size device it puts the image in a different place for me.

I tried it, it didn't work.

```
ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
int screenWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
int screenHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
int imageWidth = imageView.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();
int imageHeight = imageView.getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight();
int x = 200*(screenWidth/screenWidthcomputer)
int y =150*(screenHeight / screenHeightcomputer);
imageView.setX(x);
imageView.setY(y);
```

Comment: Why not just set the placement in XML if the location has to be the same for all phones?

Comment: Because I want the image to move when I press a button.